# AWS CloudFormation custom lambda function stuck in create state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I am trying use a value returned from lambda function via. CloudFormation custom resources; however when I try, the CloudFormation Custom resource is stuck in wait state infinitely.

The following the Lambda Node code, which I am trying and

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var date = new Date();
  var current_hour = date.getHours();
  console.log("START :: " + current_hour);

    console.log("END :: " + current_hour);
    data = {
        "val1" : "val1",
        "val2" : "val2"
    };

    result = {
      "Status" : "SUCCESS",
      "Reason" : "Success Reason",
      "PhysicalResourceId" : "LambdaCustomDelayFunction",
      "StackId" : event.StackId,
      "RequestId" : event.RequestId,
      "LogicalResourceId" : event.LogicalResourceId,
      "Data" : data
    };
    console.log('---Event---');
    console.log(event);
    console.log('---Context---');
    console.log(context);
    console.log('---Result---');
    console.log(result);

    context.done(null, result);
};
```

The following the CloudFormation script, I am trying to work with lambda

```
"DelayFunction" : {
      "Type" : "Custom::Delayer",
      "Properties" : {
        "ServiceToken" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1-123456778:function:delayfunction"
      }
      },
"MySG": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": " Server SG 1",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/16"
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ],
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "SG 1"
          },
          {"Key":"Lambda", "Value":{ "Fn::GetAtt" : ["DelayFunction", "val1"]}} <------ Trying to retrieve the value
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the CloudFormation API requires you to PUT your `result` object as a JSON-encoded body to the pre-signed `ResponseURL` provided in the request event. See the documentation on [Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html):

> 3. The custom resource provider processes the AWS CloudFormation request and returns a response of SUCCESS or FAILED to the pre-signed URL. [...] AWS CloudFormation waits and listens for a response in the pre-signed URL location. [...]
> 4. After getting a SUCCESS response, AWS CloudFormation proceeds with the stack operation. If a FAILURE or no response is returned, the operation fails.

In your example, you can replace the `context.done(null, result);` line in your Lambda function with something like this:

```
var responseBody = JSON.stringify(result);
var https = require("https");
var url = require("url");

var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
var options = {
    hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
    port: 443,
    path: parsedUrl.path,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "",
        "content-length": responseBody.length
    }
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
    console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
    console.log("Status message: " + response.statusMessage);
    context.done();
});

request.on("error", function(error) {
    console.log("send(..) failed executing https.request(..): " + error);
    context.done();
});

request.write(responseBody);
request.end();
```

See [AWS Lambda Function Code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html) for the contents of `cfn-response` module, which implements this response logic in a self-contained function. Keep in mind, however, that the `cfn-response` module can only be referenced directly when a [`ZipFile`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-zipfile) parameter provides Javascript code inline to an [`AWS::Lambda::Function`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) resource (and is limited to a max of 4096 characters). Since you're uploading your Lambda function outside CloudFormation in your example, it'll probably be easier to inline the above code directly in your existing function.

Comment: Your comments about cfn-response within a lambda are confusing. He can just include the model in his lambda as per my code. What's the point in copying and pasting it?

Comment: In the example code, the `ServiceToken` property points to an existing ARN (`arn:aws:lambda:*`), which implies the Lambda function is installed not through an `AWS::Lambda:Function` resource, but through some other means. The `cfn-response` module is only provided when using the `ZipFile` property of the CloudFormation resource (it's part of the CloudFormation resource implementation). Since the module is not automatically available he must provide it himself, either by adding the cfn-response.js module source code into his zip or by inlining it directly into the existing function.

Answer (score 1):

All I can see in your code is calls to context methods to signal completion, but you need to communicate with CloudFormation specifically (akin to cfn-signal)

Please see the cfn-response section here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

Basic example from my functions:

```
var response = require('cfn-response');
cloudwatchevents.putTargets(putTargetsParams, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                        response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, err.stack);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(data);           // successful response
                        response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS);
                    }
                });
```

Internally the response.send() calls context methods for you.